# Range-based for-loop vector iterator not incrementable

Tags: c++, vector, iterator

In my application I store all currently open windows in a vector in order to do event handling. When a window is opened it is added to the vector and removed when it is closed. I have a process event function where I iterate through that vector and update all windows with the current event:

```
    for(Window* w : windows)
        w->OnWindowEvent(event);
```

However, if I close the window I get the error 'Debug Assertion failed: vector iterator not incrementable'. From my understanding, something like this happens if the current iterator is invalidated like e.g. when erasing an element, which is what I have read here and on other sites. But I'm not doing this here. Another thing that is odd is, that if I use a 'traditional' for loop like this:

```
for(int i = 0; i < windows.size(); i++)
    windows[i]->OnWindowEvent(event);
```

then I can use the same range-based loop directly afterwards without any errors.
Am I missing on something here?

Comment: I assume closing a window would modify the container `windows`. Depending on the type of container and how you remove the element, it may invalidate some or all references and iterators to the container. You may not preform an operation on container that will invalidate it's iterators while iterating over it.

Comment: Does anything in `OnWindowEvent()` change the vector?

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux I'm only iterating over it after I made changes and I don't keep any references to the vector or an iterator

Comment: @Leon2806 Ranged based for loops use iterators in the background. You will have to worry about invalidating iterators, even if you don't handle or keep any iterators manually yourself. If `w->OnWindowEvent(event);` must never lead to any change to `windows` that invalidates iterators.

Comment: @Galik Thank you! that's it. I guess sometimes you're just blind and don't see the obvious :). I'm calling Window::Dispose in case the window received a close-event and Dispose removes the window from the container.